# Which Exception class to choose

Tags: .net, exception

Suppose you want to throw `Exception` like this:

'Project with the provided ID cannot be assigned.'

and you **don't want to write** your custom Exception class. What predefined `Exception` class would you use for this? 
(I'm talking about all classes inheriting from `Exception`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't the project be assigned? Is it because the ID provided (presumably as an argument) is inappropriate? If so, it should be an `ArgumentException`. If it's because the project's state is inappropriate for assignment, then `InvalidOperationException` would be better. If it's something else, please give more details.

Of course, there may not be anything really suitable. Sometimes the best approach really is to write your own exception class.

Comment: It's because the project is in an inappropriate state. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

[InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like `InvalidOperationException` to me...

Answer (score 0):

My practice (in the Java world) is to differentiate two cases:

- You asked me to do something silly - InvalidOperationException or InvalidArgument would work for this
- I am temporarily broken, if you try again it might work

The second case I can't see a .NET equivalent of my TransientException. Personally I would extend SystemException with a new exception class for that.